# Changed spark plugs now engine idles high

Tags: engine, audi

Just changed the spark plugs in my Audi A3 2.0tfsi Quattro after having a cylinder 1 misfire. The misfire seems to have gone but not the engine is now idling high.
Could this be an issue where the ECU learning new parameters with the plugs?
I've put NGK plugs in, and it also feels a little down on power.

Comment: Which model of NGK plugs did you use?

Comment: Double platinum think that's what they were called!

Comment: NGK model number?

Comment: What condition were the old plugs in. What is "idling high"? Is it 50, 100, 1,000 RPMs higher that normal?

Comment: One of the old plugs was brown like rust and the rpm when up to 1200 from about 750.

Comment: Don't what the model number was I'd have to check tomorrow!

Comment: That brown is probably dielectric Grease, not rust

Comment: @tgun926 - I would bet Mick is talking about electrode side of the plug and not the porcelain side.

Comment: Here's the make of spark plug, laser platinum pfr7s8eg. I did have to disconnect the maf to take the engine cover of so maybe it's the maf?

Comment: Drove the car to work this morning and the misfire has gone but it feel down on power and idle is still a bit high well just sitting in the car for 10 mins it seems to be going up and down from say 850 to 1100!!

Comment: Ok think I've got a little result, on the way home I stopped off and disconnected the maf and then drove home! There was no change with the maf disconnected so I'm I right in thinking the maf is no good?

Answer (score 2):

The most obvious cause of high idle is a vacuum leak.

Recheck all your hoses and connections.

Comment: I might of knocked the maf when taking the engine cover off! I'll check all the connections when I've finished work.

Comment: Could the coil pack be goosed? Just with it being down on power!

Answer (score 0):

I think your question about ECU parameters is spot on. Your ECU may still think it's running with the fault. Reset the ECU by unhooking the battery for 10 minutes, then reconnect and give it a try. No harm, no foul.