# Engine down on power

Tags: engine, audi

Right the high idle has gone but the engine still feels down on power, example if I'm in 5th doing about 50-60mph and I put my foot down it struggle to get up to speed! Could a could be st fault and running on 3 cylinders? My code reader doesn't pick any faults up!

Comment: what year, make, model, engine, transmission?

Comment: If you put the car in neutral and rev the engine what does it feel like? Is there any hesitation or wobbling?

Comment: This is a continuation of your first question (http://mechanics.stackexchange.com/q/38997/4939). You should update the original question with this information, or take the time to include **ALL** the details from the previous question so people don't have to ask you for all the details again.

Comment: Everything feel fine it's just the lack of power, you would think there was anything wrong with it until you put your foot down. It on a 57 plate Audi A3 tfsi Quattro, full service on 84k, it did have a misfire on cyl 1 but I changed the plugs and that seems to have sorted it. Could that coil be bad and running on 3 cylinders and causing lack of power?

Comment: Was there a carbon Trail on the spark plug that you replaced? If that's the reason it was misfiring there could be a carbon Trail on the inside of the spark plug wire boot which is causing it to misfire again. You would need to change the wires also.

Comment: It's not misfiring just lack of power! I changed the plugs because the owner before me must have spilt some oil and it's got onto the spark plug causing it to misfire so I've changed all the plugs and cleaned the chamber! The coils are all separate ones and the connection are on a rail! With there being oil spilt on cylinder 1 maybe that coil could be bad due oil?? My code reader isn't finding any codes!